# How do I set my trigger so that it fires when an event occurs on a different control?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, animation, triggers

I'm trying to perform animation of an element when a certain button, which exists elsewhere in the window, is clicked.

Here is what I have tried:

```
    <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Blue"
                CornerRadius="30" Margin="4">
            <Border.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger **SourceName="btnSearch"  RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseUp"**>
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Border.Triggers>
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ItemsControl x:Name="itmsSearch" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Padding="4"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SearchResultItemDT}">
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
```

The properties for my EventTrigger seem to have the wrong values which leads to an exception being thrown stating that no element with the name btnSearch can be found.

The said button resides elsewhere in my window:

```
    <StackPanel
        Height="30"
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        Margin="5">

        <TextBox
            x:Name="txtSearch"
            Width="650"
            FontFamily="Comic Sans MS"
            Foreground="Chocolate" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btnSearch"
            Width="100"
            Content="Go!"
            Click="BtnSearch_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
```

I just assumed that setting SourceName to the name of the required button would do the trick. But it's not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `StoryBoard.TargetName` property to the element name you want to animate.You have already set the `StoryBoard.TargetProperty`. When the `TargetName` property is not set, it assumes the current element.

You dont need to set the `SourceName`.

**Example:**

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger  RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard TargetName="jim2" TargetProperty="Opacity">
                    <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:4" 
AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
    <Image Name="jim1" Source="jim1.gif"/>
    <Image Name="jim2" Source="jim2.gif"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I tried setting TargetName="btnSearch", but that did not do anything... no response. Even so, this sounds a little backwards, I think? My trigger is in the Border element as shown in the question, so I shouldn't have to set TargetName... the Border itself is the target. I want the animation specified in the Border to occur when the Click event of the button is fired.

Comment: Also, I tried to move the trigger into my Button element (so now it was <Button.Triggers>, and THEN I tried to set TargetName to the name of my Border element... and I still got the "element with that name not found" exception.

Comment: WOOPS! Okay, you were right. What I posted in my previous comment worked. It was just that I had specified my entire content section as a resource. When I moved it to my actual element's content, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could use the visualstatemanager to do your animations (add the vsm to the control (or any parent) that should be animated). and you can start the animation in your click handler of your button.

```
VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(this.myControlToAnimate, "MyAnimationState", true)
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to do what I want in XAML?